# How to run PowerShell code to notify admin when user makes a new forwarding rule?

Tags: powershell

I need to quickly produce Alerts Policies for when users produce forwarding rules. A PowerShell command is the most ideal solution as it can easily run it for multiple accounts.

I know there is a longer way of producing it through the Microsoft Portal - Security and Compliance interface. However, this method takes to long given the number of accounts this needs to be implemented for. The code below shows what it should look like. There is one parameter that specifies the event that prompts and alert. I believe this part needs to be changed to detect when a forwarding rule is produced.

My code below:

```
New-ProtectionAlert -Name "Forwarding Rule Detected" -Category ThreatManagement -NotifyUser helpme@domain.com.au -ThreatType Activity -Operation <THIS IS WHERE IT NEEDS TO SPECIFY WHAT PROMPTS AN ALERT> -Severity Low -Description "Alert when user produces forwarding rule" -AggregationType None
```

This link is the documentation for the command above:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/policy-and-compliance/new-protectionalert?view=exchange-ps

This link is the documentation that lists events that can be taken as parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance#audited-activities

Comment: Do you get any error message? What did you try so far? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why don't you create the desired alert in the console and then use `Get-ProtectionAlert` to see the resulting `Operation` parameter?